# listactivity is stuttering caused by WindowManager

Tags: android, list, listview, listactivity, logcat

i have a question regarding some weird logcat outputs.

Scenario:
I have a listactivity with images and textviews, etc. The images are loaded by Fedor's implementation of LazyList. I changed his cache to a LRUMap from commons.

On scrolling i got sometimes a stuttering and logcats shows me a lot of this messages:

```
V/WindowManager( 2482): Dsptch > Window{48267640 <packagename to Listactivity> paused=false}
V/InputDevice( 2482): ID[0]=0(0) Up(1=>0)
```

Any ideas what these messages mean?

Thx in advance

Comment: On what device are you seeing this?